# How to hide request and response from monitoring

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

In my kotlin project i am using retrofit to send request receive response. I need to hide my request and response from monitoring. I found the following app do the same ( check the screenshot ) . How to hide my request and response ?

My retrofit code is given below

```
object RetrofitHelper {

   val baseUrl = "http://73.108.176.155/"

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKWNz.jpg)